# Sharp sword on the throat

Tags: talmud-gemara, pikuachnefesh-danger-life, tractate-brachot

The Gemara says Berachot 10a

> אפי' חרב חדה מונחת על צוארו של אדם אל ימנע עצמו מן הרחמים

Even if a **sharp** sword is resting on one's thought he shouldn't hold back from (asking for) mercy."

Why does the Gemara have to say "sharp" rather than just a sword? A sword usually makes a connotation of sharpness.

Comment: Are we so madkadek on the choice of words the Gemara uses on non-halachic matters?

Comment: @HodofHod, I think so (though I can't point to a specific example at the moment).

Comment: Please explain the downvote so I can fix my question and further help you.

Comment: The phrase exists in Tehillim 57:5. I think it's just a pleonasm.

Comment: sharp swords work faster the quote is implying last second a dull sword might not be able to do the Job hence more time

Comment: @simchashatorah Consider Shulchan Aruch YD 18:7

Comment: wat does it say there?

Comment: @simchashatorah It says it can take a long time to slaughter an animal with a knife that is not sharp. See also YD 23:4.

Comment: seems to be giving a worst case scenario, but then why not say even if one is thrown in a furnace or a lion's den. why did it choose human executioner which implies there is some hope left.

Answer (score 4):

I have heard in the name of Rabbi Nachman M'Breslov that חדה (Chada) is Roshei Teivos חולאים (illnesses), דמים (money), and הריון (pregnancy). Even if one is very ill, or lacking money, or having a difficult time conceiving they should never give up.

Comment: I found this, but no primary source: http://www.fxp.co.il/showthread.php?t=12106034